# Can't see nginx port via "docker ps" command

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have an nginx container up and running (see below picture), but the configured port (8585) is not displaying, as result the related symfony 4 project is not running via `localhost:8585`

[image]

Here is nginx configuration in docker-composer.yml file:

```
version: "3.6"

services: 

    #Core configuration

    php-fpm:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_php-fpm
        build:
            context: .
            target: base
        ports:
            - '${PHP_PORT}:9000'
        volumes:
            - './:${WORKPATH}:rw'
            - './docker/php/conf/dev/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
            #- './docker/php/conf/dev/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
        env_file:
            - .env    
        restart: always

    nginx:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - '${NGINX_PORT}:80'
        volumes:
            - './:${WORKPATH}:rw'
            - './docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx'
            - './docker/nginx/conf/dev/api022020.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
            #- './docker/nginx/conf/dev/api022020.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
            - './docker/nginx/conf/core/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
        links:
            - php-fpm
        env_file:
            - .env    
        expose:
            - 80    
        restart: always    

    # Frontend configuration
    node:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_node
        build: './docker/nodejs'
        ports:
            - '${NODE_PORT}:3000'
        entrypoint: "yarn watch"
        volumes:
            - './:/usr/src/app:rw'
        restart: always

    #DB configuration 
    # For dev environment coding
    mysql:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - '${MYSQL_PORT}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - 'mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        restart: always

    #For prod environment emulation    
    postgresql:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_pgsql
        image: postgres:9.6-alpine
        environment:
            PGSQL_DATABASE: ${PGSQL_DATABASE}
            PGSQL_USER: ${PGSQL_USER}
            PGSQL_PASSWORD: ${PGSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - '${PGSQL_PORT}:5432'
        volumes:
            - 'db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw'
        restart: always

    #Server optimization    
    redis:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_redis
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
            - '${REDIS_PORT}:6379'
        links:
            - php-fpm
        restart: always    

volumes:
    db-data: {}
    mysql:
```

Please check out my nginx .conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;       # Added this line
    listen [::]80 default_server;   # Added this line
    #server_name my-project.dev;

    root /var/www/api022020/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    #Prod
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/api022020_prod_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api022020_prod_access.log;
}
```

.env file:

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=5f41c23b077589c815d289434ec7aeb4
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: #"postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
# DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

## Docker
CONTAINER_NAME=api022020
WORKPATH=/var/www/api022020
PHP_PORT=9500
NGINX_PORT=8585
REDIS_PORT=8283
NODE_PORT=8382
MAILDEV_PORT=1080
APACHE_PORT=8189

## MySQL
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=api022020
MYSQL_USER=api022020
MYSQL_PASSWORD=api022020
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=api022020

## POSTGRESQL
PGSQL_PORT=5342
PGSQL_DATABASE=api022020
PGSQL_USER=api022020
PGSQL_PASSWORD=api022020
```

**UPDATE:**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine as base

ENV WORKPATH "/var/www/api022020"
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS icu-dev postgresql-dev libzip-dev gnupg graphviz make autoconf git zlib-dev curl chromium go \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql --with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip intl pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql opcache json pgsql mysqli \
    && pecl install apcu redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu mysqli redis 

#Custom php configuration
COPY ./docker/php/conf/dev/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

#Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN wget https://cs.symfony.com/download/php-cs-fixer-v2.phar -o php-cs-fixer \
    && chmod a+x php-cs-fixer \
    && mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer \
    && curl --insecure -LS https://get.sensiolabs.de/deptrac.phar -o deptrac.phar \
    && chmod a+x deptrac.phar \
    && mv deptrac.phar /usr/local/bin/deptrac

RUN mkdir -p ${WORKPATH}    

RUN rm -rf ${WORKPATH}/vendor \
    && ls -l ${WORKPATH}

RUN mkdir -p ${WORKPATH}/var \
    && mkdir ${WORKPATH}/var/cache \
    && mkdir ${WORKPATH}/var/logs \
    && mkdir ${WORKPATH}/var/sessions \
    && chown -R www-data ${WORKPATH}/var \
    && chown -R www-data /tmp

RUN chown www-data:www-data -R ${WORKPATH}

WORKDIR ${WORKPATH}

COPY . ./        

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]

#Production environment
FROM base

COPY ./docker/php/conf/prod/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
patrick@patrick-VirtualBox:/var/www/api022020$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                               NAMES
0241c049f90c        redis:alpine          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8283->6379/tcp              api022020_redis
a58155e52d7f        nginx                 "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   22 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes                    0.0.0.0:8585->80/tcp                api022020_nginx
3aab21fb15aa        postgres:9.6-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 46 seconds ago                                       api022020_pgsql
0cf51b9359a8        api022020_node        "yarn watch"             22 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 42 seconds ago                                       api022020_node
087648a69e68        8ee96c1a7995          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                   0.0.0.0:9500->9000/tcp              api022020_php-fpm
7de9e9a59252        mysql:5.7             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   api022020_mysql
```

When trying to access `localhost:8585`, it seems not to work:

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8585/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

**UPDATE 3**

Getting `Bad Request` error when replacing nginx image with apache image as following:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8189
```

Apache container configuration:

```
# Apache
    apache:
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_apache
        image: tutum/apache-php
        ports:
            - "${APACHE_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - '${WORKPATH}:/var/www'
            - './docker/php/conf/dev/php.ini:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/30-custom.ini'
            - './docker/apache/sites:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'
        environment:
            - "ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true"
        links:
            - "mysql:mysql"
            - "maildev:maildev"
        env_file:
            - .env    
        restart: always 


    # Maildev
    maildev:
        image: djfarrelly/maildev
        ports:
            - "${MAILDEV_PORT}:80"
```

Any hints as how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Including the environment variable settings would be helpful.  The one obvious thing in the question is that you're setting nginx to listen on port 8585, but you're not publishing that port out of the container, only the default HTTP port 80.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please clarify what you mean by publishing the port out of the container? I have the all ports set in my .env file. In the picture with purple background above, you can see that other containers ports are displayed, the issue is only with nginx port

Comment: Please post formatted text rather than a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe forgot to load .env

```
php-fpm:
    ...
    env_file:   # <-- Add this
        - .env  # <-- Add this

nginx:
    ...
    env_file:   # <-- Add this
        - .env  # <-- Add this
    ..
```

**Update1:**

Make sure the Dockerfile you go `EXPOSE 80`

docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
  ...
  expose:
    - 80
  ...
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;       # Add this line
    listen [::]:80 default_server;  # Add this line

    #server_name my-project.dev;

    root /var/www/api022020/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    #Prod
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/api022020_prod_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api022020_prod_access.log;
}
```

if still not working, can you please provide logs from the failed nginx container `docker-componse logs --tail=500`

**Update2**:

How do you load you secret into your environments ? for postgres for example

docker-compose.yml (read https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

```
...
postgresql:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_pgsql
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${PGSQL_DATABASE}          # <-- Change the left key
        POSTGRES_USER: ${PGSQL_USER}            # <-- Change the left key
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PGSQL_PASSWORD}    # <-- Change the left key

node:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}_node
    build: './docker/nodejs'
    ports:
        - '${NODE_PORT}:3000'
    entrypoint: "yarn watch"                    # <-- change "entrypoint" by "command"
    volumes:
        - './:/usr/src/app:rw'
    restart: always
...
```

Have you update your nginx.conf to listen a port ? (I gave you lines on update1)

**Update3**:

My fault, syntax error:

`listen [::]80 default_server;` -> `listen [::]:80 default_server;`

Comment: Settings are similar for all containers, but this issue is encountered only with nginx container as you can see in the picture above.

Comment: Please notice that I've updated my post to provide the whole docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I've just tried the idea ("Update1") from @Jean-Jacques MOIROUX, as result the nginx port is now displaying in the CLI (please check out "UPDATE 2" in my first post). However, the project is not accessible (see "UPDATE 2")

Comment: Update2 with some new changes

Comment: The are configured only in my .env file (see whole file above). I've tried to replace nginx image with apache image, it seems to work, I'm getting "Bad request" error (which means it works). I don't think the issue with nginx has to do with secret key configuration since apache is working with the same configuration

Comment: the same `env_file` I told you to add on my first post :-), check your original docker-compose there is no `env_file` set. The Most important that, is everything work, I'm just sad that you have to be force to work with Apache not your first choice, enjoy docker life !

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how I can get nginx up and running. I've made all changes you wanted me to make including `env_file` setting (please check out my first post)

Comment: `docker volume prune` & `docker network prune` if you can do it, will wipe everything, but sometime cache cause issues when trying some stuff

Comment: I made a syntax error `listen [::]80 default_server;` -> `listen [::]:80 default_server;`